# Javascript array reduce returns empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is this simple example returning an empty array?

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
const result = arr.reduce((list, val) => {
  list.push[val];
  return list;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `list.push[val];` => `list.push(val);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [**Array.prototype.push**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) in the wrong way.

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
const result = arr.reduce((list, val) => {
  list.push(val);
  return list;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: D... I missed the square brackets, boh. Thanks!